# Jquery jTable - how to add multiselect dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

i want to add multiselect functionality to a field.
here is my current code for configuring jtable.
how to implement multiselect functionality for a specified field

```
fields: {
        firstName: {
            title: 'name',
            width: '20%'
        },
        surname: {
            title: 'surname',
            width: '20%'
        },
        userName: {
            title: 'username',
            width: '20%',
            key: true,
            create: true
        },
        enabled: {
            title: 'status',
            type: 'radiobutton',
            options: [
                {Value: true, DisplayText: 'enabled'},
                {Value: false, DisplayText: 'disabled'}
            ],
            width: '20%'
        },
        roles: {
            /***********************************************
            // i wanna to enable multi-select for this field
            /***********************************************
            title: 'roles',
            options: [
                {Value: "ROLE_ADMIN", DisplayText: "admin"},
                {Value: "ROLE_USER", DisplayText: "user"}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field Type should be `multiselectddl`

Make sure you are using the jTable files available in this repository

https://github.com/stanleyta/jtable/commit/6876303615a239dc409dee481a877a8f934f340d

Comment: the multiselectddl doesn't exist in version 2.4 ?

Comment: Its in 2.4. I have validated by downloading lib files from this path https://github.com/stanleyta/jtable/archive/6876303615a239dc409dee481a877a8f934f340d.zip

Comment: It is in version 2.5.  Upgrading is easy as you only need jquery.jtable.js.  I downloaded it from github.com/volosoft/jtable/blob/master/jquery.jtable.js

Comment: FYI...I had to modify the code for the toolbar to also have a select dropdown control, but borrowed the same code from the github link above to apply to the _addToolBarItem method.